# What is the best way to clean up output from a failed Spark job?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, pyspark, etl, aws-glue

I am running a Spark job that writes Parquet files to an S3 bucket.

My output files are partitioned like so: `/year=2020/month=8/day=8/hour=0/`, etc. All job runs write to the same S3 prefix and a job will likely have results in multiple partitions.

This job could fail for a variety of reasons (OOM, S3 throttling, etc.), and when it does, it frequently leaves hundreds or thousands of `part-*.snappy.parquet` files in the destination S3 bucket.  Because of this, I don't *think* I can use `overwrite` mode as it will overwrite the results of previously *successful* job runs. Is there a best practice when it comes to cleaning up partially finished job runs?

Some options I've considered:

1. Each job run does write files using a GUID in all filenames. This could be used to manually find the files that are from the failed job run and remove them. The problem with this is that the GUID is not exposed to the Spark job (as far as I can see) so finding the GUID for a failed job (without manual inspection, of course) seems like the challenge.
2. Write files to a location that's not the final destination and only after the job finishes successfully, move these files to their final location.

Option 2 seems reasonable but requires extra components to this ETL pipeline.

As a new Spark/AWS Glue user, it would be nice to find out the best practices before I attempt to re-invent the wheel. What patterns are popular for cleaning up failed Spark jobs and what are their pros and cons?

Comment: As mentioned in  https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-etl-glue-arguments.html can you enable enable-s3-parquet-optimized-committer by setting it to true in your job parameters. This will skip creating temp files and renaming them ?

Answer (score 0):

So whenever we write data using spark, we need to pass just the folder path and we cannot control the file names. Now considering this you can always overwrite the output while writing to the target directory.

```
df.write.mode('overwrite').parquet(path)
```

This way your target will always we replaced.

Comment: An important detail that I left out: The data is partitioned like so: `year=2020/month=08/day=10/hour=00/`. A job run will write to multiple partitions and I am always writing to the same folder. So, if I use `overwrite` mode, then I will lose results from previous _successful_ job runs. I updated the original question to add this detail.